# How do you break a persistent login in a Codeception acceptance test?

Tags: codeception

I recently took on a new role at work in the form of using Codeception to create acceptance tests. As this is a learning experience for me I have been dumping a lot of questions onto Stack Overflow. Thanks for all of your help! But here is my newest dilemma. First of all, I am running a cept test. First, it logs in to a website, runs a bunch of tests, then logs out:

```
$I->am('user');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->wait('2');
$I->amOnPage('?realm=ab-cd');
$I->amGoingTo('Login to website');
$I->fillField('username', 'REMOVED');
$I->fillField('password', 'REMOVED');
$I->click('Sign In');
$I->expect('Signing In');
// Should be on dashboard
$I->wait('5');
$I->see('Dashboard');
$I->see('Messages');
$I->see('Assignments');
$I->see('Reports');
$I->see('Help');
$I->click('Sign Out');
$I->expect('Signed Out');
$I->wait('5');
$I->makeScreenshot('Screenshot');
$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/');
```

The screen shot it takes is as if it never logged out. I have tried both clicking the sign out button, and also using the id(as above) to select the sign out button. The problem here, is that i have multiple tests running and when this does not sign out, it makes my next test fail. Is there a way to force sign out a user doing a cest test?
I saw in articles about an issue like this a few years ago, but looks like since has been fixed. I tried all recommendations from those articles. Any thoughts?

The link in question that provides the Sign Out:

```
<button id="log-out" class="red-btn">Sign Out</button>
```

UPDATE: After adding the line $I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/');
        An error occurs:

```
[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnexpectedAlertOpenException] Unexpected modal
dialog (text: Fallback login. Enter password): Fallback login. Enter
password
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using BrowserStack to run the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you go to / after logout?
Shouldn't logout take you there automatically?

Your test is not checking if it logged out successfully.
`Expect` method is just a comment.
Use [see](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#see) or [seeCurrentUrlEquals](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#seeCurrentUrlEquals) to verify success of logging out.

Comment: I used the $I->amOnPage('/') as an attempt to try to force it back to its initial url as my attempts to log-out were failing.

Comment: Please add relevant parts of HTML to your question.